# Android Wifi-Hotspot Port Forwarding

Tags: android, tcp, udp, hotspot

How can I make a port forwarding from a android device whose Hotspot is ON to another device who is connected to that hotspot.

I want to connect to my system server which is connected to a android Hotspot from another device which is in another network. When I use the pubilc IP of the Hotspot device I am getting access to that device only, I am not able to access to other device which is connected to it.

As how the WIFI-router provides the port forwarding in the same case I want in android when I am using Hotspot.

Comment: So basically you want to jump networks? Not possible

Comment: As how the router provides the port forwarding in the same case I want in android using Hotspot.